# Can't install Java JDK 8 64-bit on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, installation, java

When trying to install Java SE Development Kit 8 on my Windows 10 laptop, I get error 1335 every time. I tried many times unsuccessfully to resolve this problem.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I can't read your image. Could you post the text in it?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are trying to install a Java 8 build that is more than a year old?  It sounds like the installer is simply corrupt.  Download [Java 8 update 201](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) instead